# 2 Sharepoint lists showing same columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, sharepoint, sharepoint-apps

I have a problem regarding my Sharepoint online application.
It's a provided hosted app which i'm debugging on my own computer.

I have 2 different lists which i deploy with the app when i install it.

One list called ReminderList and one list called ReminderStatus.
Both of theese lists gets deployed to Sharepoint but they get the same Columns even though i've specified them differently.

I've tried giving them a unique content type with unique column names.
But still when they gets deployed they get the same column names but with unique data in the first column.

Anyone had this issue before?

Github: https://github.com/simmeyo/ReminderServiceApp

Comment: Please add your code for us to get more details.

Comment: https://github.com/simmeyo/ReminderServiceApp

Comment: Add the code **into** the question please. Do not just provide a link to outside source. This is for the sake of clarity for future readers of your question.

Comment: Both your lists have the same `TemplateId`, the same `Sequence` nuber and the same field GUID for the `ID` field. So they're not distinct in their definition. That will cause the problem.

Comment: @LInsoDeTeh That was correct, thanks!